# How can I find all uses of an imported symbol in a TypeScript AST?

Tags: typescript

Given a [`SourceFile`](https://thejohnfreeman.github.io/TypeScript/interfaces/export_.sourcefile.html) with some [`ImportDeclaration`s](https://thejohnfreeman.github.io/TypeScript/interfaces/importdeclaration.html), how can I find all nodes in the `SourceFile` that reference an imported symbol? I know how to solve this problem in the general case by constructing scopes and namespaces and resolving references, but I'm asking if this functionality is already waiting in the TypeScript Compiler API somewhere.